# Sass @import not importing partials

Tags: npm, sass, gulp

I'm a noobie to pro npm / gulp-style workflows and I'm using a repo called react-starterify to build a simple webapp.

I'm trying to add partial scss files using @import "variables"; in my main.scss file. However, in the final compiled css file it's actually printing "@import 'variables';" at the top of the file instead of pulling it in as part of the file.

What am I missing?

Here is my gulpfile.babel.js:

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
import browserify from 'browserify';
import watchify from 'watchify';
import source from 'vinyl-source-stream';
import buffer from 'vinyl-buffer';
import eslint from 'gulp-eslint';
import babelify from 'babelify';
import uglify from 'gulp-uglify';
import rimraf from 'rimraf';
import notify from 'gulp-notify';
import browserSync, { reload } from 'browser-sync';
import sourcemaps from 'gulp-sourcemaps';
import postcss from 'gulp-postcss';
import rename from 'gulp-rename';
import nested from 'postcss-nested';
import vars from 'postcss-simple-vars';
import extend from 'postcss-simple-extend';
import cssnano from 'cssnano';
import htmlReplace from 'gulp-html-replace';
import imagemin from 'gulp-imagemin';
import pngquant from 'imagemin-pngquant';
import runSequence from 'run-sequence';
import ghPages from 'gulp-gh-pages';

const paths = {
  bundle: 'app.js',
  entry: 'src/Index.js',
  srcCss: 'src/**/main.scss',
  srcImg: 'src/images/**',
  srcLint: ['src/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.js'],
  dist: 'dist',
  distJs: 'dist/js',
  distImg: 'dist/images',
  distDeploy: './dist/**/*'
};

const customOpts = {
  entries: [paths.entry],
  debug: true,
  cache: {},
  packageCache: {}
};

const opts = Object.assign({}, watchify.args, customOpts);

gulp.task('clean', cb => {
  rimraf('dist', cb);
});

gulp.task('browserSync', () => {
  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: './'
    }
  });
});

gulp.task('watchify', () => {
  const bundler = watchify(browserify(opts));

  function rebundle() {
    return bundler.bundle()
      .on('error', notify.onError())
      .pipe(source(paths.bundle))
      .pipe(buffer())
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distJs))
      .pipe(reload({ stream: true }));
  }

  bundler.transform(babelify)
  .on('update', rebundle);
  return rebundle();
});

gulp.task('browserify', () => {
  browserify(paths.entry, { debug: true })
  .transform(babelify)
  .bundle()
  .pipe(source(paths.bundle))
  .pipe(buffer())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distJs));
});

gulp.task('styles', () => {
  gulp.src(paths.srcCss)
  .pipe(rename({ extname: '.css' }))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(postcss([vars, extend, nested, autoprefixer, cssnano]))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist))
  .pipe(reload({ stream: true }));
});

gulp.task('htmlReplace', () => {
  gulp.src('index.html')
  .pipe(htmlReplace({ css: 'styles/main.css', js: 'js/app.js' }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist));
});

gulp.task('images', () => {
  gulp.src(paths.srcImg)
    .pipe(imagemin({
      progressive: true,
      svgoPlugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }],
      use: [pngquant()]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distImg));
});

gulp.task('lint', () => {
  gulp.src(paths.srcLint)
  .pipe(eslint())
  .pipe(eslint.format());
});

gulp.task('watchTask', () => {
  gulp.watch(paths.srcCss, ['styles']);
  gulp.watch(paths.srcLint, ['lint']);
});

gulp.task('deploy', () => {
  gulp.src(paths.distDeploy)
    .pipe(ghPages());
});

gulp.task('watch', cb => {
  runSequence('clean', ['browserSync', 'watchTask', 'watchify', 'styles', 'lint', 'images'], cb);
});

gulp.task('build', cb => {
  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
  runSequence('clean', ['browserify', 'styles', 'htmlReplace', 'images'], cb);
});
```

**I'm also noticing another issue where it sees a variable in a @mixin as undefined. e.g.**

```
@mixin blacklinks ($link, $visit, $hover, $active, $disabled) {
    a,
    .text-btn-black {
        @include a1;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        color: $link;
        &:visited {
            color: $visit;
        }
        &:hover {
            color: $hover;
        }
        &:active {
            color: $active;
        }
        &:disabled {
            color: $disabled
        }
    }
}
```

**It fails at $link, where that var is being sent from another partial _base.scss.**

```
@include blacklinks($black, $black, $mediumgray, $darkgray, $disabledtext);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install and use the [`postcss-import`](https://npmjs.com/package/postcss-import) package.

Here's a simplified but working example:

**gulpfile.js**:

```
import atImport from 'postcss-import';

gulp.task('styles', () => {
  gulp.src(paths.srcCss)
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.css' }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(postcss([atImport, vars, extend, nested, autoprefixer, cssnano]))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist))
    .pipe(reload({ stream: true }));
});
```

**src/styles/main.scss**:

```
@import 'variables.scss';

.foo {
  color:$c;
}
```

**src/styles/variables.scss**:

```
$c: blue;
```

Comment: I added another issue below the gulpfile.bable.js code.